# Should I generate IDs in PHP or in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have a web application in which I want to create a section to fill receipt information.

I need some information such as customer ID, customer name, customer address, customer tellephone number, product ID, sales agent ID, order number, and order date. The customer ID, order number, order date, agent ID and product date will be stored in one table.

Will it be better to

- generate the customer id using the `mt_rand()` function in PHP based on some criteria so that this info gets directly to the order table without any further queries or to
- generate this ID in MySQL and query the database again to get this info and store in the order table (and I will need to store the customer ID in who bought a specific product in the orders table).

Which approach is better? Is there another approach that I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL. For example, 
create table 
(   INT AUTO_INCREMENT) )

Let the id generation be taken care of MySQL instead of having your code generate a number and store it in database

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not possible with `varchar`.

Comment: varchar is just an example. You can use it with number

Comment: I finally decided to let mysqly generate the customer id for me. I will use transaction in mysqli, such that when i add a customer, i will use the select statement to get back the id from the customer tables and insert into the orders table for a specific product a customer bought

Comment: This will also course a problem on how will i  know wc product a specific customer bought

Comment: You will have to store that info in a separate table, like purchase and have a mapping of both customer id and product id.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use to `SELECT uuid()` in phpmyadmin

Comment: @JFMeier A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)